# How to have an evenly divided UL over several rows

Tags: html, css, layout, html-lists

I have an unordered list with blocks. Simplified the code looks as follows:

```
<ul style="list-style-type: none;">
<li style=" float:left"><table style="width:200px; height:200px">[blockcontent]</table></li>
<li style=" float:left"><table style="width:200px; height:200px">[blockcontent]</table></li>
etc.
</ul>
```

This will show as much blocks on a row as there is space for. On a wide page there might be 5 blocks in a row after which it skips to the next line. If the page is smaller it will reduce the number of blocks to 4,3,2 and finally 1. Very basic responsive design.

The problem is that this "float:left" puts everything at the left side of the page. I would like to have it evenly spread over the width of the page.

The solutions I have found on the internet are all very complicated. I would like to know what is the most simple and elegant solution for this kind of problem.

Those tables are tables to order their internal parts. For the outside they are just fixed blocks of 200x200 that might as well be divs. They will never be smaller or bigger. The question is about the space between them.

Comment: Whatever you do, those tables will mess things up for you. What are those tables? Are all tables with same cols/rows? The question is incomplete without these details. Create an MCVE, see here for how -- [MCVE]

Comment: you can set li as inline-block instead float, then use text-align and text-align-last on ul to tune the layout as you wish. test and play with : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eWJWYa

Comment: @GCyrillus: this works nice, except for the fact that justify also influences the content of the table: the strings are stretched to cover the whole width.

Comment: the strings ? li remains 200px on each sides . flex could stretch them, but inline-block doesn't , they are spread evenly on each rows, exept last one where number of item can vari.Sorry I do not understand what you mean :)

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking can be achieved using `flexbox`

Please remove inline styles.

And don't need to use tables here.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;
  justify-content:center /* or space-between or space-around*/
}

li {
  flex: 0 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>[blockcontent]</li>
  <li>[blockcontent]</li>
  <li>[blockcontent]</li>
  <li>[blockcontent]</li>
  <li>[blockcontent]</li>
  <li>[blockcontent]</li>
  <li>[blockcontent]</li>
  <li>[blockcontent]</li>
  <li>[blockcontent]</li>
  <li>[blockcontent]</li>
  <li>[blockcontent]</li>
  <li>[blockcontent]</li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Really admire your solution. Plain simple, easily understandable.

Comment: Thanks @LucasMedina

Answer (score 0):

You can make your `ul` a flex-container with the following settings:

(but remove the floats in this case)

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

li {
  background: #ddd;
  margin-top: 2px;
}
```

```html
<ul style="list-style-type: none;">
  <li>
    <table style="width:200px; height:200px">[blockcontent]</table>
  </li>
  <li>
    <table style="width:200px; height:200px">[blockcontent]</table>
  </li>
  <li>
    <table style="width:200px; height:200px">[blockcontent]</table>
  </li>
  <li>
    <table style="width:200px; height:200px">[blockcontent]</table>
  </li>
  <li>
    <table style="width:200px; height:200px">[blockcontent]</table>
  </li>
  <li>
    <table style="width:200px; height:200px">[blockcontent]</table>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: why a downvote here ?  Beside , If flex, no need to remove float on children where it can be usefull for old browsers, it will be overriden by the flexmodel where implemented.

Comment: @GCyrillus I was wondering too. I now added a background for the blocks to make it clearer - it's basically the same method as the upvoted answer, just with more of the original code left in.

Answer (score 0):

Just add CSS columns to your ul and control it with column-width.

```
ul {
 column-width: 200px;
 column-fill: balance;
}
li { break-inside: avoid; }
```

`break-inside: avoid;` on `li` will prevent `li`s from breaking columns.

**Fiddle Playground:** https://jsfiddle.net/nc4ah4ta/

**Snippet:**

```css
ul {
 column-width: 200px;
 column-fill: balance;
}
li { break-inside: avoid; }
table { border: 1px solid #ddd; }
```

```html
<ul style="list-style-type: none;">
<li><table style="width:200px; height:200px">[blockcontent]</table></li>
<li><table style="width:200px; height:200px">[blockcontent]</table></li>
<li><table style="width:200px; height:200px">[blockcontent]</table></li>
<li><table style="width:200px; height:200px">[blockcontent]</table></li>
<li><table style="width:200px; height:200px">[blockcontent]</table></li>
</ul>
```

---

If you are using tables only for creating blocks, then you don't need those in fact.

**Snippet:**

```css
ul {
 column-width: 200px;
 column-fill: balance;
}
li { break-inside: avoid; padding: 12px; }
```

```html
<ul style="list-style-type: none;">
<li>[blockcontent]</li>
<li>[blockcontent]</li>
<li>[blockcontent]</li>
<li>[blockcontent]</li>
<li>[blockcontent]</li>
</ul>
```

---

You can fine-tune your layout using `column-count` to control the number of columns. This in conjunction with media-queries will allow you to further refine its responsiveness.

`column-gap` will allow you to define the width of the gap between columns.

And `column-rule` will allow you to have separators between the columns.